# Custom headers in nginx: log first, clean afterwards

Tags: nginx, log-files, http-headers

I need to parse nginx `access_log` and associate records with user accounts. To do so, I decided to use a custom header:

1. App sends custom header (like `x-userid`)
2. Nginx stores that value in access_log with custom log format `$sent_http_x_userid`
3. The header is being cleared and so the client doesn't see it with `more_clear_headers 'x-userid'`

Logging works just fine, I can see the proper userids in access_log. However, if I turn on the clearing part, the access_log shows '-' instead of actual userid.

Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible to log the header from the app before sending it to the client and then empty it with nginx?

Is there a better way to make this work? The app is PHP7, nginx is 1.10.3

Comment: Could you show your custom log format?

Comment: Basically it's default combined log with 1 extra field:
`log_format coolname '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                      '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent [uid=$sent_http_x_userid] '
                      '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';`

Comment: Try to log `$upstream_http_x_user_id`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, you should post this as an answer so I can accept - it works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `$sent_http_x_userid` variable name literally means that [header was *sent*](https://nginx.org/r/$sent_http_) to client. When you clean it, nginx will not send it and there will be no variable `$sent_http_x_userid`.

But what you actually need is to log header that you've *received* from upstream. For that there is [`$upstream_http_x_userid`](https://nginx.org/r/$upstream_http_) variable that you can write to log.

And if you don't want to pass this header to client, there is [`proxy_hide_header`](https://nginx.org/r/proxy_hide_header) directive.

So all together could look like this

```
log_format coolname '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent [uid=$upstream_http_x_userid] '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

server {
    ...
    access_log /var/log/nginx/cool.log coolname;

    location /whatever {
        proxy_pass http://your-app;
        proxy_hide_header x-userid;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using `more_clear_headers` to hide the header from end client.

Comment: @ValPetruchek proxy_hide_header will do the same

Comment: this is rather confusing. I'm not a devops/sysadmin, just a fullstack dev whose stack is apparently becoming too full. As a developer, I believe there's a reason for having 2 different ways of achieving the same goal.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this would be simple, just store the header's contents in a variable (using "set"), and use that variable in your log_format, disregarding the cleared header.  But that failed miserably: the set command is executed before calling the backend (when the upstream headers have yet to be set).

But using LUA was succesful:

```
            set $saved_uid "X";
            header_filter_by_lua_block {
              ngx.var.saved_uid = ngx.var.upstream_http_x_userid;
            }
            more_clear_headers 'x-userid';
```

and use the variable in log_format:

```
log_format coolname
  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
  '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent [uid=$saved_uid] '
  '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried @AlexeyTen's answer first because it's an easier one - and it works.